# How can I filter an EntityType in my form with roles?

Tags: symfony4

I'd like to show in a Synfomy formType a select input which only proposes users with a particular role.

I'm currently writing an app which involves some basic users and some super-users that are in charge of the basic users.

So whenever I sign-up a new user, I want to be able to assign him to a designated "super-user" to be managed by.

But when I try to make an entityType field in my registrationType to select the super-user to be assigned, I don't know how to display only users with the ROLE_MANAGER in the choice. I only understand how to display all users.

All users are in the same table.
I make a distinction between them using Symfony roles system only.

I've tried to look at a query_builder solution, but I didn't understant how to look in arrays with the "where" parameter or apply role hierarchy in that query.

My formType is as follow.
I'm trying to display only users with ROLE_MANAGER and higher in their roles in the "manager" entityType select input.

Roles are stored in arrays like this : ["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_MANAGER","ROLE_ADMIN"]... so user.roles returns this kind of array.

```php
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('manager', EntityType::class,[
                'class' => User::class,
                'choice_label' => 'username',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er){
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
                }])
            ->add('password',PasswordType::class)
            ->add('confirm_password',PasswordType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'validation_groups' => ['Default', 'registration'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Could anyone point me toward the right direction ?

Many Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe user roles are stored in a stringified array, which makes it harder to query with something like `==`. What you can do however is to use the `LIKE` operator. This will look for a pattern. In your case if you only want to show users with `ROLE_MANAGER` you can use:

```
 ->andWhere('u.roles LIKE \'%ROLE_MANAGER%\' ')
```

Put this in your line above `->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');`.

**Be aware:** if you have other roles containing `ROLE_MANAGER` these will also be returned with when using `LIKE` with `%`...`%`. You can read more about the sql LIKE operator [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

*ps*. You might be wondering why I would use `andWhere()` instead of `where()`. This is done habitually because `where()` could remove previous `WHERE` statements in the actual SQL query if there were any, so I try to avoid it. and use `andWhere()` instead.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much ! It actually works pretty well as a solution ! Thank you as well for the addiotionnal explaining about "andWhere()", it actually solves another issue I was having ! Only downside here is that it doesn't apply role hierarchy, but for this particular use, it turns out to be better like this ! Thank you very much again !

Answer (score 0):

You should simply precise it in your query (and avoid as far as you can using raw strings in your code) :

```
//somewhere in your project
class User
{
    const ROLE_MANAGER = 'ROLE_MANAGER'; //or in your config, parameters etc
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $role = User::ROLE_MANAGER;
        // OR something like this if you think you gonna 
        // need to reuse this formtype with other roles restructions : 
        // $role = $options["role"];

        //...
                       ->andWhere(':role IN u.roles')
                       ->setParameter('role', $role)
```

Another cool thing in DQL is that it adds some sugar on standard SQL operations. 
For example, in a use case that is close to this one, you could need to use "MEMBER OF" keywords that allows you to search for a particular entity in a collection :

```
                      ->andWhere(':manager MEMBER OF u.managedBy')
                       ->setParameter('manager', $user)
```

Hope it helped !

Comment: That's actually helpfull as well ! A more subtle approach, I didn't manage to implement it so far without errors but ultimately I'll try and make it this way. I really gotta brush up on DQL, the MEMBER OF operator seems way to powerfull to ignore ! Thank you very much !